# Why is the LM386 so noisy when powered from wall?

Tags: audio, noise, lm317, lm386

I am using an LM386 to amplify an electret signal.  Configuration for a gain of 200x is shown below. When powered from my bench power supply in quiet conditions, the output is around 4 mV (RMS).   When powered from the wall using an RAC03-12SK AC/DC converter to generate a 12 V supply with a 220 μF bypass capacitor, the output in quiet conditions is around 160 mV (RMS).

Is there something wrong with my wiring, or is this just a really noisy supply? Is there a quick fix using a small number of parts, or do I just need a better power supply? It's just a hobby circuit, so it doesn't need to be pretty.

[image: LM386 pin configuration]

The position of the LM386 in this circuit is shown below.  The LM386 is a pre-amp, followed by a rectifier, integrator, and another amplifier.  The result is fed into a comparator with adjustable reference.  With bench power supply, everything works as designed, but with the wall supply the comparator is always HIGH because of the noise amplification.

[image: sound threshold detector]

The power supply circuit is shown below. There is also a 220 μF bypass cap (not shown) on the PCB board with the LM386.

[image: power supply subcircuit]

Comment: Doesn't the electret itself require about 1.5-2.0 V to operate? Or is it a different kind than I'm used to seeing?

Comment: You're right... I'm using an LM317 to generate 3V for the electret off of the 12V supply.  Also correcting the part number in my original post.

Comment: So I'd like to see the whole circuit, including the electret and its 3 V supply rail, any resistors or capacitors, and how it all then connects to IN. I don't need to see the LM317, though.

Comment: Is the noise you see at your AC/DC converter's switching frequency (130 KHz)?  You're running with no bypass cap on the amplifier (just 220uF on the power supply which probably does little or nothing) and no filtering on the switching supply, so you will be very sensitive to its noise.

Comment: @periblepsis I have added the microphone and adjustable reference going into the LM386.

Comment: @user1850479 It sounds like you've identified a potential cause of the issue, but I'm afraid I don't understand enough about power supplies to understand your comment.  You say I have no bypass on the LM386, but I thought that's what the 47uF cap was for.  I will add more details on the power supply circuit.

Comment: @broken.eggshell I should not have said no bypass because you do have the dedicated bypass pin.  However, I would still bypass the VCC pins too, both because your power supply says to use an MLCC on its output and because you have a lot of ripple.  And smaller values would work better, maybe a 1 uF 0603.  Hopefully that 47uF isn't an electrolytic capacitor?

Comment: I have added the power supply circuit to the question.

Comment: @user1850479 I will look into the additional bypassing.  As for the 47 uF, guilty.

Comment: You shouldn't be using electrolytics at all for a power supply like this, so switch them out for MLCCs routed as tight as possible.  Your edits show that you have the inverting input directly connected to the output of the SMPS, is that right?  You'll be directly amplifying the power supply output...

Comment: I will use an SMD cap in the future for this kind of thing.  I get your point about amplifying noise.  Would it help if I just bypass the lower half of the voltage divider that sets the reference voltage at the inverting input?

Comment: Both of the LM386 schematics are weird. Either they have just drawing errors, or design faults. The output should not be taken from the bypass pin. And why there is an adjustable reference on positive input? It is an LM386, an audio amp, not an op-amp.

Comment: Right now any supply noise goes directly to the negative input. Yes the RAC3 is noisy. The 12 V rail needs filtering, and the negative input might profit from a bypass cap to ground as well.

Comment: Where are your decoupling capacitors?

Comment: With a 12 V supply, the LM386 isn't going to do better than 3.5 V RMS into an 8 Ohm load. Looking at the electret and assuming you use a divider and capacitor filtered 10 V rail (not a 3 V rail, which isn't as good) for the electret, you could then apply a 15 K load resistor instead of 2.2 k to get more gain out of it. Then, for 94 SPL level you'd need a voltage gain of about 85, not 200. But I'm guessing SPL. So 200 isn't inconsistent, I suppose. But I wouldn't use 3 V for this electret. I'd go higher than that.

Comment: The inverting input should be grounded unless you have a good reason for doing otherwise. For a typical audio amp application, the LM386 "self biases" its inputs and output correctly all by itself. It's not an opamp - don't try to treat it like one. Refer to the [TI datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf) for standard examples.

Comment: Your second circuit shows input on positive and first shows input on negative.  Edit your second circuit showing the correct circuit!

Comment: @Justme I have corrected the circuit diagrams and shown the full circuit.  The output of the LM286 feeds into a rectifier-integrator-amplifier combo, which eventually leads to a comparator (which is always HI when wall-powered because it's amplifying noise).

Comment: @broken.eggshell But if you don't plan to drive a speaker or other low impedance load, and you have already two op-amps and a comparator, why add the LM386 at all? You could just use an op-amp for amplification.

Comment: I wanted to be able to set my voltage threshold to correspond to a very low SPL, down to the noise floor on the mic (a few or tens of uV I guess).  But I was concerned that the rectifier wouldn't work on such a tiny signal, hence the LM386 pre-amp.  Either way, I suspect the power supply ripple is probably affecting the op-amps too.  I just focused on the LM386 because that's where it's most obvious (wall vs. bench supply is 4 mV vs 160 mV).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142682/discussion-on-question-by-broken-eggshell-why-is-the-lm386-so-noisy-when-powered); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly, you have a noisy switching power supply. Especially in a high gain circuit, this is pretty much a no-no for audio. They are used but must be designed for much lower output noise than your typical wall wart. You can check with a scope set to AC, look at the power rails on the most sensitive range. I find an old fashioned analogue scope best for this.

My experience (I did a fair amount of analogue audio design back in the day) has been that trying to filter these general purpose wall supplies to get the HF noise down to an inaudible level is a lost cause, especially when you have significant gain. You can try multiple stages of LC filtering, but in practice this does not remove enough noise. The stray paths around discrete components will always allow a few mV of nasty switcher noise (which is typically around 80-100kHz, and often changes frequency with load) to get through.

Given that for audio we want at least 80dB of dynamic range, a few millivolts is enough to be audible. The issue is that the noise is at frequencies which easily modulate into the audio band as a low level tone of a few kHz, and as our ears are extremely good at detecting this kind of signal, it is far more of a problem than white or pink noise at that kind of level would be.

Back when I was designing audio (until about 2000) almost everything had a normal unregulated supply followed by a pair of linear regulators, giving something like +/-17V. (In fact at my [website](https://www.danmcb.com/en/tech/music-technology/rebuild-of-an-audio-mixer-power-supply/) I have an article showing the rebuild of such a beast, used on a small analogue mixing console from the 1990s.) This kind of large PSU was ubiquitous at the time. (And yes, they were heavy.)

The UK company [Chord](https://chordelectronics.co.uk/) were (to my knowledge) one of the first to use switching supplies in their power amps, but they were not ordinary in design. And indeed, the amps were far lighter than most others in the market, at no sacrifice in quality. Also, for a power amp you can get away with more noise than you can for a mic amp, which demands an absolutely clean power source.

These days, if I open up a piece of modern audio gear (like [this one](https://www.arturia.com/drumbrute/overview)) what I generally find is a pair of switching regulators giving something like +/-18V DC, followed by linear regulators which get the output noise down. This arrangement seems to work fine, and it also makes the heat design of the unit far easier, as the voltage across the linear regulators remains small and constant, unlike the linear power supplies of old.

Anyway, this long ramble is by way of background, but the short answer is that if you have a lot of gain, filtering the noise off that switcher and using it to directly power the analogue circuit is likely to still result in annoying audible artifacts.

Comment: It might be the supply, but the schematics how the LM386 is used don't make much sense either.

Comment: Yeah I really need to get a scope...

Comment: @danmcb Are you saying that wall supplies in general or switching supplies like the RAC are not typically used for audio/high-gain applications?  What would be my best alternative?  I guess there's always batteries...

Comment: As long as proper grounding (and shielding) techniques are followed, it should be possible to filter power supply noise to a negligible level. Of course, with most switching supplies, there will be sharp high frequency transitions that can radiate and couple into the circuit. For sensitive analog circuitry, ZVS, resonant, and other methods may be needed.

Comment: @broken.eggshell I will edit the question to answer this.

Answer (score 2):

I can add something about the electret but can't go past that point because I really do not understand why you are using an LM386, now that you've added so much more to the question. It just seems *wrong*-minded, now that my prior assumptions have been thrown out by your additions. So I'll just focus on why I disagree about using an LM317 set for \$3\:\text{V}\$.

These electrets usually specify no more than about \$500\:\mu\text{A}\$ and often take less -- closer to about \$350\:\mu\text{A}\$ would be more the expectation. This is a very low-current requirement.

They are typically supplied using a current-limiting resistor -- not unlike what's used for LEDs. Since an electret presents a fairly high impedance, most of the noise (or lower frequency ripple) on the voltage supply gets applied across the electret and appears pretty much unattenuated there. So a quiet supply helps.

All this can be handled without the need of a linear regulator IC. It's low current and resistors and capacitors are sufficient.

You are using a \$12\:\text{V}\$ power supply. Use that, to start. Don't use an LM317. Especially because using an LM317 to generate a very low voltage (\$3\:\text{V}\$) also lowers the gain. And it is usually better to go for more gain at the 1st stage, than less, because the signal to noise ratio that occurs in the 1st stage can only be reduced by trading off bandwidth once it has moved past the 1st stage transducer. (There are sources of leakage shot noise due to leakage from lead 1 to the JFET gate via the reverse-biased diode, for example. Not by any means the only source, though.)

Just a quick look at the diagram shows \$R_{_\text{L}}\$ used as the current limit resistor for the device. The specifications will tell you what value they used when developing the rest of the specifications. This does ***not*** mean that you have to use the same value. It just means that this is what they felt was within a typical use and also showed off their device in a better light.

[image]

Looking at the specifications:

[image]

First thing I notice is that the signal-to-noise (S/N) specification uses A-weighting (see purple box near the bottom.) This may have been chosen to cover over *hum components* and make the S/N number look better. Not sure. But anyone using A-weighting makes me suspicious.

Next thing to notice is the operating voltage range (orange box.) Since I want to use a higher voltage rail to get better voltage gain out of the device, but without exceeding these specifications, I'm likely to pick a value of \$8.5\:\text{V}\$ for two reasons: (1) It provides better voltage gain than \$3\:\text{V}\$ and probably better S/N; and, (2) The supply can be replaced with a standard alkaline \$9\:\text{V}\$ battery (which typically only provides about \$8.5\:\text{V}\$ after a little usage, anyway.)

Both the green box and the blue box show/use \$R_{_\text{L}}=2.2\:\text{k}\Omega\$. They don't call it \$R_{_\text{L}}\$, per se, but it's implied that this is the same load as shown in the earlier diagram.

In the blue box they also show a supply voltage of \$3\:\text{V}\$ being used. This doesn't in any way mean that I have to use that voltage. But this says the electret capsule requires \$3\:\text{V}-2.2\:\text{k}\Omega\cdot 500\:\mu\text{A}=1.9\:\text{V}\$ at a minimum. The \$500\:\mu\text{A}\$ figure in the blue box is a *maximum* case and since JFETs vary a lot (unfortunately) it may require more than that to operate. So more margin is a good idea -- at least \$2.5\:\text{V}\$ in my book.

This is yet another good reason to use a higher voltage -- namely \$8.5\:\text{V}\$.

A remaining question is about the subcircuit needed to make the supply. The maximum supply current is already known to be \$500\:\mu\text{A}\$. But what about changes made by the sound? That can be computed by using the maximum sensitivity and the maximum expected sound pressure level (SPL.) An SPL of 100 is considered 'very loud', so this can be computed using \$\frac{20\:\mu\text{Pa}}{2.2\:\text{k}\Omega}\cdot \left[10^{^\frac{100-42}{20}}\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{Pa}}\right]\approx 7.2\:\mu\text{A}\$ RMS. So a peak of no more than about \$10\:\mu\text{A}\$. I conclude the signal won't present an added problem.

So here's what I'd try:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTeamv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At the very maximum current there will be at least \$2\:\text{V}\$ for operating the electret. At lower operating currents (device variation), the operating voltage for the electret will be higher. But under no circumstances can it come close to exceeding the maximum specification of \$10\:\text{V}\$ (which would imply an operating current of \$\le 100\:\mu\text{A}\$ (not likely.)

The load impedance is \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ so the maximum output with an SPL of 100 will be about \$70\:\text{mV}\$ RMS, assuming maximum sensitivity. Likely closer to around \$50\:\text{mV}\$ RMS for typical devices and an SPL of 100.

The above should help isolate the electret from the power supply rail noise (and allow the use of a 9 V battery if you want to try that.) It also gets more gain out of the electret than the \$3\:\text{V}\$ supply does.

I have to stop here. Your additions answer some questions while creating many more.